# Read file without extension from shared drive in Python

Tags: python, file, shared

I'm experiencing difficulties with accessing and reading a file without extension(which is a json inside, need to read it somehow, but I can't access it) from a shared drive.

This is what I've tried so far:

First try:

`open(r"X:\\shared_drive\Notes").read()` on this one I'm getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

Second try:

```
with open(r"\\DESKTOP-xxx\shared_drive\Notes", 'r') as f:
      f.read()
```

And on this one I'm getting `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:`

Comment: I don't know if Python can work with shared drives but I would start with `os.listdir()` to check what filenames Python sees in folder. Maybe your file has name `Notes.txt` but Windows hide extension and you see only `Notes`.

Comment: pretty sure `os.listdir()` doesn't work with shared drives. It can't find the path or I am not typing it correctly. I can list it tho when I do ```for diskDrive in c.Win32_Share():
    print(diskDrive)``` where I am using WMI protocol with credentials to the remote host.

Comment: I would start with `os.listdir(r'X:')` and later `os.listdir(r'X:\shared_drive')`, etc.

Comment: @furas It cannot find the drive `X:`.

Answer (score -1):

instead of writing the path as:

```
\\DESKTOP-xxx\shared_drive\Notes
```

Have you tried using `os` package:

```
import os.path
file_to_open = os.path.join("DESKTOP-xxx", "shared_drive", "Notes")
f = open(file_to_open)
```

Or `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path
data_folder = Path("//DESKTOP-xxx/shared_drive/Notes")
file_to_open = data_folder / "Notes"
f = open(file_to_open)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the `os` package. On the first one that you provided it doesn't find the file `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` and on the second it says `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`. Can this be something related with drive permissions and authentication??

Comment: try data_folder = Path("\\\\DESKTOP-xxx/shared_drive/Notes")

Comment: It is still`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: The pathname construction is not the issue here; they are correctly using a raw string literal.